# Large - Normal in Multiple Screens Android

Tags: android, screen, multiscreen

Through as [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) , there are 4 types of screens :

```
xhdpi
hdpi
mdpi
ldpi
```

I want to know WHAT IS EXACTLY SCREEN SIZE ( in PIXEL ) of these ? :

```
normal-xhdpi                      large-xhdpi
normal-hdpi                       large-hdpi
normal-mdpi                       large-mdpi
```

These screen sizes is given by Eclipse :

```
xhdpi :    768 x 1280 
          2560 x 1600
           720 x 1280

hdpi :     480 x 800
           480 x 854

mdpi :    1280 x 800
          1024 x 600
           480 x 854
           480 x 800
           320 x 480
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See you are mixing the concepts. small,medium,large and xlarge are screen sizes whereas ldpi,mdpi,hdpi , xhdpi,nodpi and tvdpi are screen densities

According to [Android Developer's website](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

**SIZE**

```
small   -   Resources for small size screens.
normal  -   Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
large   -   Resources for large size screens.
xlarge  -   Resources for extra large size screens.
```

**Density**

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). 
        (This is the baseline density.)

hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
nodpi   Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. 
        The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, 
        regardless of the current screen's density.
tvdpi   Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 
        213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly 
        intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and 
        hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as 
        appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources,  
        you  should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. 
        For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi.
```

Now the minimum resolution of each size is defined below

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Also from the android Docs

> The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: pixels = dps * (density / 160). For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dp would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dp units to define your application’s UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens.

**Which means two different devices with different densities can have the same number of dp but not same pixels.**

Answer (score 1):

This Formula worked for me to get the screen size and convert them into pixels :

```
float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 
int pixels = (int) (120 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Comment: All i want to know is such as : normal-xhpdi is 720x1280, large-xhdpi is 768x1280, etc... Anyway thank for giving your code.

Comment: simply put ur dp variable in scale and use the formula above...u will get the answer..i hv provided clear answer. try once and let me kno